# Ruby on Rails - Nested Devise form validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

guys!

I have an Customer form with an nested User form (I'm using Devise) where you can add as many users you want.

When I have to edit only the customer I don't know how to skip an user password validation (when I have a form with only 1 user I just use the method **update_without_password**).

Do you guys have any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check models/customer.rb and look at the "validates" line, check that the password is not "presence: true" which means that it is always required

Comment: No. There is no "presence: true" in the Customer model.

In the User model I have **validates :password, presence: true, on: :create**, but it's not working because it's called in the update also.

Answer (score 0):

In customer model you must have something like:

```
validates_associated :user
```

Try changing it to:

```
validates_associated :user,on: :create
```